# Cant download pygame

Tags: python, pygame

This is the error I get when I try to download pygame.

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hkauem4n\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hkauem4n\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-k1_a0_dp'
         cwd: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hkauem4n\pygame\
    Complete output (17 lines):


WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
Using WINDOWS configuration...


Download prebuilts to "prebuilt_downloads" and copy to "./prebuilt-x64"? [Y/n]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hkauem4n\pygame\setup.py", line 194, in <module>
    buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hkauem4n\pygame\buildconfig\config.py", line 210, in main
    deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hkauem4n\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 576, in main
    and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hkauem4n\pygame\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 302, in ask
    reply = raw_input(
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Can't find an answer anywhere to this problem, can someone help me, please?

Comment: Please the code that you are running before this error. Try and work in a virtual environment like conda

Comment: pip install pygame

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue a while ago. You have to download visual studio c++ build tools to download pygame.

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019

Go there and scroll down until you see Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019 and download that. Then run "pip install pygame" and it should work.